# SQL WHERE CONTAINS statement referencing columns not static text

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, contains

I have these data below:

```
FName | Lname | Notes                  | Flag
-----   -----   -----                    ----
John    Smith   John Smith didn't know     1
Bill    Jones   Tom Johnson knows          0
```

I need to create and populate a variable (Flag) which looks at the Notes column, searches for values in Fname and Lname column, and assigns a 1 if Notes contains both Fname and Lname values, or 0 if it contains only 1, or none of the values from Fname and Lname.

I have looked at CONTAINS, LIKE, and INSTR, but I am having trouble with the references, the examples I see want me to enter a static value to search on ("John"), rather than a column reference ("Fname").

I'd like to write a CASE statement that says

- Look in each row, if the Notes field contains the values in the Fname and Lname fields, Flag =1, else, Flag =0.

I have tried

```
CASE
    WHEN
    (
    SELECT
        Fname, Lname, Notes
    FROM
        table
    WHERE CONTAINS ((Notes, Fname) AND (Notes, Lname)) > 0
    )
    THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
    AS Flag
    FROM table;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Put the case expression in the select list instead.

Comment: `contains` is a non-standard operator. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: AHWNN - It's an Oracle DB, I added the tag.
JarlH - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the coalesce/isnull is necessary.

```
select
case 
    when ((Notes like '%' + coalesce(u.FName,'') + '%')  and (Notes like '%' + coalesce(LName,'') + '%'))
    then 1
    else 0
end Flag
from Table


update t
set t.Flag = 
    case 
        when ((Notes like '%' + coalesce(u.FName,'') + '%')  and (Notes like '%' + coalesce(LName,'') + '%'))
        then 1
        else 0
    end
From Table t
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN
        t.Notes LIKE '%' + t.FName + '%'
        AND 
        t.Notes LIKE '%' + t.LName + '%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END AS Flag
FROM
    table AS t
```

However, if you really just want to filter where the Flag = 1, you don't need this as a column:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table AS t
WHERE
    CASE WHEN
        t.Notes LIKE '%' + t.FName + '%'
        AND 
        t.Notes LIKE '%' + t.LName + '%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END =1
```

Comment: I'd like to have the actual column, otherwise yeah you're right I could just filter. 

Thank you so much for your help!